# If polymorphism is the ability of different types to share the same interface, is there a name for a single type that fulfills different interfaces?

Tags: object-oriented, interfaces, polymorphism

Consider this example of polymorphism. I have two different *API*, *IWrite* and *IRead*, and then a single implementation of these.

```
interface IRead
{
    Entity Find(int id);
}

interface IWrite
{
   void Persist(Entity);
}

class SomeRDBMSRepository : IRead, IWrite
{
   public void Persist(Entity entity)
   {
      ...persist it
   }

   public Entity Find(int id)
   {
      ...return an entity
   }
}
```

Because the implementation has all the details of how to implement the interfaces, then we could easily use the same type,  *SomeRDBMSRepository*. We could have several clients of the APIs, maybe like these:

```
 class FindUserQueryHandler
    {
        public FindUserQueryHandler(IRead readEntities)
        {
        }

        public User Handle(int id)
        {
            return _readEntities.Find(id);
        }
    }
class RegisterUserCommandHandler
{
    public RegisterUserCommandHandler(IWrite writeEntities)
    {
    }

    public void Handle(User user)
    {
        _writeEntities.Persist(user);
    }
}
```

When we want to stress the idea of polymorphism, then we simply create new types that provide different functionality. We give this example when we have, let's say, a requirement that the users must be queried from a different repository, then we could create a new type, `SomeNoSQLRepository : IRead` and in this way **FindUserQueryHandler** can use an instance of this implementation without caring about its actual details, as long as the type implements the `IRead` API. Also **FindUserQueryHandler** doesn't have to do anything special (ie to change)

Someone asked me a while ago for an example of polymorphism (*cough* / interview) and I gave him the example of `SomeRDBMSRepository` because I think this type has different roles or responsibilities for different clients. For a *query* type is the *reader*, while for the command is the *writer*. So my reason was this type is `poly` because it has the `IRead` form and the `IWrite` form in the same time. It seems I was wrong.

While reading the polymorphism definition from Wikipedia, I could adapt it to the meaning that if we can use any type in the place where some API is expected, as long as that type implements the clearly defined API, then that code is polymorphic. The mechanics don't really mater. C# or Java requires to specify that a class implements an interface, but for a language like Go there is enough to be a match of the method signatures between the type and interface.

Wikipedia also says that a polymorphic type is a type that has operations that can accept objects of different types. In my example the query and command types are polymorphic types by this definition.

Basically my question is: is there a taxonomy for `SomeRDBMSRepository`? How wrong I was?

Comment: [God object?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/12446/31260)

Comment: @gardenhead has a good answer.  Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping.  Polymorphism in OOP is often referred to as inclusion polymorphism in broader contexts, because there are also other kinds of polymorphism.

Comment: What you have there is often referred to as multiple inheritance (multiple interface inheritance in Java and C# as they don't have full multiple inheritance, I have not seem many languages that do full multiple inheritance properly). Polymorphism usually refers to multiple implementations inheriting from a single interface, to that one implementation can stand in for another.

Comment: That's what my interviewer said about inheritance, but I didn't agree much with him, because what is missing here is the behaviour/implementation inheritance, unlike C++. I reviewed the Gamma et. all introductory chapter of their book and I believe the whole point is, like you said, the ability to substitute an object to another, so the clients don't depend on a particular object, but on interfaces. Interface in Gamma is different from the interface from C# or Java. Gamma considers the object's interface the totatity of its public methods. A type is a name to denote a particular interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your definition is wrong. You are using the term *type* incorrectly. Here is your definition

> polymorphism is the ability of different types to share the same interface

Types don't have interfaces; interfaces *are* types. Polymorphism is in fact the ability of expressions to take on multiple types. In OOP, the expressions are objects and the types are interfaces.

The example you gave is correct. An object of class `SomeRDBMSRepository` actually has three types: `SomeRDBMSRepository`, `IRead`, and `IWrite`, so it is polymorphic (trimorphic?). Your interviewer was wrong in this instance, which unfortunately happens quite often in tech interviews.